# 'Method Not Allowed' Error in Spring Boot Feign Client GET Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-cloud-feign

I am having problems with my feign client, and I'm an intern so I may not be able to exactly explain my problem.

This is my controller endpoint in my backend service:

```
  @GetMapping("/all")
  @Transactional
  public ResponseEntity<FindAllItemsOutput> findAll(@RequestParam Boolean showDeleted,
                                                    @RequestParam Optional<Integer> pageNumber,
                                                    @RequestParam Optional<Integer> pageSize,
                                                    @RequestParam Optional<String> titleContains,
                                                    @RequestParam Optional<String> descriptionContains) {

    FindAllItemsInput input = FindAllItemsInput.builder()
            .showDeleted(showDeleted)
            .pageNumber(pageNumber)
            .pageSize(pageSize)
            .titleContains(titleContains)
            .descriptionContains(descriptionContains)
            .build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        findAllItemsOperation.process(input));
  }
```

When executing various GET requests it returns the correct data.

When I am accessing this endpoint through a backend for frontend through Feign, I am getting the following:

```
2023-08-07T14:27:41.686+03:00 ERROR 19052 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: feign.FeignException$MethodNotAllowed: [405] during [GET] to [http://localhost:1234/item/all%7B?params%7D] [ZooStoreRestExport#findItemsInternal(String)]: [{"timestamp":"2023-08-07T11:27:41.638+00:00","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","path":"/item/all%7B"}]] with root cause

feign.FeignException$MethodNotAllowed: [405] during [GET] to [http://localhost:1234/item/all%7B?params%7D] [ZooStoreRestExport#findItemsInternal(String)]: [{"timestamp":"2023-08-07T11:27:41.638+00:00","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","path":"/item/all%7B"}]

And also the following in the main application:
2023-08-07T14:41:25.232+03:00  WARN 21136 --- [nio-1234-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]
```

This is my Rest Export:

```
default FindAllItemsOutput findAll(
          Boolean showDeleted,
          Optional<Integer> pageNumber,
          Optional<Integer> pageSize,
          Optional<String> titleContains,
          Optional<String> descriptionContains) {

    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("?showDeleted=").append(showDeleted);
    pageNumber.ifPresent(page -> urlBuilder.append("&pageNumber=").append(page));
    pageSize.ifPresent(size -> urlBuilder.append("&pageSize=").append(size));
    titleContains.ifPresent(title -> urlBuilder.append("&titleContains=").append(title));
    descriptionContains.ifPresent(description -> urlBuilder.append("&descriptionContains=").append(description));

    return findItemsInternal(urlBuilder.toString());
  }

  // Internal method to make the actual Feign request
  @RequestLine("GET /item/all{?params}")
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
  FindAllItemsOutput findItemsInternal(@Param String params);
```

And this is how i call it in the BFF controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<FindAllItemsOutput> findAll(@RequestParam Boolean showDeleted,
                                                      @RequestParam Optional<Integer> pageNumber,
                                                      @RequestParam Optional<Integer> pageSize,
                                                      @RequestParam Optional<String> titleContains,
                                                      @RequestParam Optional<String> descriptionContains) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(zooStoreRestExport.findAll(
                showDeleted,
                pageNumber,
                pageSize,
                titleContains,
                descriptionContains
        ));
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried modifying a lot of the code, including hardcoding the rest export endpoint to an endpoint, which is working in the main service

Comment: The URL in the error message looks weird: `http://localhost:1234/item/all%7B?params%7D`. Probably because you used this `?` in the URL of the `@RequestLine` annotation. You are probably doing something wrong there with the request query parameters, but I'm not familiar with Feign so I don't know the exact solution.